# Tensorflow importing crashes Python without any error on Windows

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, matplotlib

Yesterday I was trying to solve matplotlib problems on Windows, which included solving `from matplotlib import ft2font` error. I have added `HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=2` for that. But today I found, that tensorflow doesn't work anymore:

```
> python                                                                                              
Python 3.5.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr  7 2018, 04:52:34) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32   
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                
>>> import tensorflow as tf                                                                           

>
```

It thinks 30 seconds, then exits Python without any error.

Where can I see logs or crashdumps or something?

Comment: Is this `tensorflow-gpu`? Have you checked (in a virtualenv or something) if `tensorflow` (CPU-only build) works? Just to check if it's a CUDA problem. I think (can't remember for sure) I got the same when I tried to use a relatively new version in an older CPU, because of the AVX instructions. I think last version without AVX on Windows is 1.5.1. What version are you using? And do you know if your CPU supports AVX?

Answer (score 12):

If you try `import h5py`, and get **ImportError: DLL load failed**, you probably have some problem as mine. Try:

> 1. Uninstall `h5py` via anaconda navigator, some relative libs (`tensorflow`) will be uninstalled as well.
> 2. Go VM path in anaconda installation, `D:\Anaconda\envs\YOUR_VM\Lib\site-packages`, delete `h5py` and `h5py-2.8.0-py3.6.egg-info` folders
> 3. Reinstall `tensorflow` or `tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: Despite python is a nice language for programming, installing packages with conda is such a hassle! Solving environment costs half an hour and now numerous times has "remove this and install this again" be the solution to problems. Very frustrating.

Comment: I can't believe that worked! Had the same issue and this does indeed fix it. However, in step 3 you MUST install tensorflow via conda, not via pip, otherwise you get the same issue

Comment: Thanks!!! how did you figure out it was `h5py`. FYI - for me it worked when I updated `h5py`